# Why is while(scan.hasNext()) skipping if statement?

Tags: java

My code seems like it is going from my second `while(scan.hasNext())` to  `if(word.compareTo(larg)>0)` and skipping over   `if(word.compareTo(small) < 0)` it should be printing   `pw.println("First word will be: " + small);` but it will only print "First word will be: " and does not print small however it will print  `pw.println("Last word will be: " + larg);`

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter createFile = new PrintWriter("temperature.txt");

    createFile.println("82.5\n30\n92\n78\n32\n98.8\n-1\nbanana\ngrapes\nanimal\nStop\n45");

    createFile.close();

    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

    float c;
    String cel;
    String stop = "Stop";

    String small = "";
    String larg = "";
    File f = new File("temperature.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("celsius.txt", true);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        float can = scan.nextFloat();
        if (can == (-1)) {
            break;
        } else
            c = (can - 32) * 5 / 9;
        cel = String.format("%.2f", +c);
        pw.println(cel);
    }

    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        String word = scan.nextLine();
        if (!word.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
            if (word.compareTo(small) < 0) {
                small = word;
            }
            if (word.compareTo(larg) > 0) {
                larg = word;
            }
        } else
            break;
    }

    pw.println("First word will be: " + small);
    pw.println("Last word will be: " + larg);
    
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        double num = scan.nextDouble();

        if (num >= 1 && num <= 50) {
            while (num <= 59) {
                pw.print(Math.pow(num, 2) + ", ");
                num++;
            }
            num++;
            pw.print(Math.pow(num, 2));
        }
    }
    pw.close();
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("celsius.txt"));

    while (input.hasNext())
        System.out.println(input.nextLine());
    // TODO code application logic here
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Answer (score 0):

You initialized `small` as an empty string.
Any non-empty string will be greater than that one. You therefore never re-assign small.

You might try this:

```
if (small.isEmpty() || (word.compareTo(small) < 0))
  small = word;
if (large.isEmpty() || (word.compareTo(large) > 0))
  large = word;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help I understand what's wrong now

Comment: If this resolves your problem you might consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

Checking if `small` and `larg` are empty is necessary to handle the scenario where these variables haven't been assigned any values yet. If they are empty, it means no words have been assigned to them, and the current word should be assigned to them without considering lexicographical comparisons.

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
        String word = scan.next();
        if (!word.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
            if (small.isEmpty() || word.compareTo(small) < 0) {
                small = word;
            }
            if (larg.isEmpty() || word.compareTo(larg) > 0) {
                larg = word;
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Changing the code to this will give the following result:

```
First word will be: animal
Last word will be: grapes
```

Comment: Thank you for the help this makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

> *'... it should be printing   `pw.println("First word will be: " + small);` but it will only print "First word will be: " and does not print small however it will print  `pw.println("Last word will be: " + larg);` ...'*

This is because the following condition is never met, since *small* is empty.

```java
if (word.compareTo(small) < 0) small = word
```

Check *small* first.

```java
if (small.isEmpty() || word.compareTo(small) < 0) small = word
```

Additionally, you need to use *[next](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#next())*, rather than *nextLine*.

```java
String word = scan.next()
```

Here are some recommendations for your code.

Use a *[try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement* for the *PrintWriter* and *Scanner* objects.

And, you are using *"[append mode](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileWriter.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File,boolean))"*, for *FileWriter*.  This is for appending data to existing files.
This is uncorrelated to the *[append](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Writer.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence))* method.

```java
new FileWriter("celsius.txt", true)
```

Here is a re-factor.

```java
try (PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter("temperature.txt")) {
    w.println("82.5\n30\n92\n78\n32\n98.8\n-1\nbanana\ngrapes\nanimal\nStop\n45");
}
try (PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("celsius.txt"))) {
    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("temperature.txt"))) {
        double v;
        String s, first = null, last = null;
        while (in.hasNext())
            if ((v = in.nextDouble()) == -1) break;
            else w.printf("%.2f%n", (v - 32) * 5 / 9);
        while (in.hasNext())
            if ((s = in.next()).equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) break;
            else if (first == null || s.compareTo(first) < 0) first = s;
            else if (last == null || s.compareTo(last) > 0) last = s;
        w.println("First word will be: " + first);
        w.println("Last word will be: " + last);
        while (in.hasNext())
            if ((v = in.nextDouble()) >= 1 && v <= 50) {
                while (v <= 59) w.print((v * v++) + ", ");
                w.print(++v * v);
            }
    }
}
try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("celsius.txt"))) {
    while (in.hasNextLine()) System.out.println(in.nextLine());
}
```

Output

```
28.06
-1.11
33.33
25.56
0.00
37.11
First word will be: animal
Last word will be: grapes
2025.0, 2116.0, 2209.0, 2304.0, 2401.0, 2500.0, 2601.0, 2704.0, 2809.0, 2916.0, 3025.0, 3136.0, 3249.0, 3364.0, 3481.0, 3721.0
```